# "Type" or "type in" context

Tags: word-choice, phrasal-verbs

Could you tell me if I should use *type* or *type in* the sentence below?

> If need to know where our retail stores are located, you could just go to Google Maps and **type**/**type in** the name of out shops and it'll show all the shops in your city.

Do both work there perfecty well in the context?

Comment: Both are grammatical in context, although there is a disconnect between loose, casual instructions "go to Google Maps" (assumes the user is familiar with the website) and oddly *specific* instructions "type in the name" (assumes the user does not know how to search). A simpler message might be: "Find our nearest stores with Google Maps." and a link that includes *Current+Location* and the name of the stores in the url, according to https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/urls/get-started#forming-the-url

Comment: Are you asking for the best way to form this sentence, or are you asking for the correct verb to use in a search box?

Comment: gotube: I'd like to know both please